# Open , closed or neither

Tags: general-topology

Determine if the set {0,1,1/2,1/3,1/4...} is closed, open or neither.

Justify your answer

What I was trying to prove that if the set A is closed if the A complement is open, but I could not figure it out

Comment: Open or closed in the usual topology of $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: If as Chou say is the ususal topology for real numbers and with Nitrogen's hint, now put in your mind what property/axiom in the definition of a *topology* you could use to prove that the complement  in $\mathbb{R}$   of your genuine set, is open.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look at neighborhoods of $0$. Can you find one that is contained in $K=\{0,1,1/2,...\}$?

Try to write $\Bbb{R}\backslash K$ as a union of open intervals and deduce that $K$ is closed.

Comment: would you please explain a bit more.

Comment: K complement =(0,1) union (1/2,1) union (1/3,1) union ......... Should I do something like this

Comment: More like $(-\infty,0)\cup (\frac{1}{2},1) \cup (\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}) \cup ...$.

Comment: I could not get it out of this !

Comment: consider the set K={0,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...}. The set K is said to be closed if Kc is open .


Kc = (-∞,0)∪(1/2,1)∪(1/3,1/2)∪.....
Thus,
(-∞,0)∪{∪ (1/(j+1),1/j)} ∪ (1,∞)
which is open. Hence, K is closed

Comment: That's right,you got it.

Comment: Thanks a lot . It been a great help